# How can I return true when the condition of where clause is false?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables like this:

```
// Posts
+----+---------+-----------------+----------+
| id |  title  |    content      |  amount  |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------+
| 1  | title1  | content1        | NULL     |
| 2  | title2  | content2        | 1000     |
| 3  | title3  | content3        | 5000     |
| 4  | title4  | content4        | NULL     |
| 5  | title5  | content5        | 2000     |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------+
//                                 ^ NULL means that question is free


// Money_Paid
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | post_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 123     | 2       |
| 2  | 345     | 5       |
| 3  | 123     | 5       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

**All I'm trying to do:** Some of my posts aren't free and anybody wants to see them should pay their cost. Now I need a query to check current user paid the cost of that post or not? *(just for non-free post)*

```
select *, 
     (select count(1) from Money_paid mp where p.amount is not null and mp.post_id = p.id and mp.user_id = :user_id) paid
from Posts p 
where p.id = :post_id
```

---

Here is a few **examples**: *(based on current tables)*

```
$stm->bindValue(":post_id", 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindValue(":user_id", 123, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// paid column => 1 (the user of '123' can see this post because he paid post's cost)

$stm->bindValue(":post_id", 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindValue(":user_id", 345, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// paid column => 0 (the user of '345' cannot see this post because he didn't pay post's cost)

$stm->bindValue(":post_id", 5, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindValue(":user_id", 345, PDO::PARAM_INT);
// paid column => 1
```

---

**What's my problem?** The output of my query is `0` when the post is free. *(While I need `1` when post is free)*.

Again. I need `1` for both free posts and paid users, And `0` for unpaid users. To easy handle it by PHP like this

```
if ($result['paid'] == 1) {
    // show it
} elas {
   // doesn't show it
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just curious why you need three outputs - why not just query whether the user can see the post or not, whether free or they paid?

Comment: @AbraCadaver You are right. But My query returns `0` for both unpaid users and free posts. I need it returns `1` for free posts. How can I do that? To easy handle it in php: `if ($result['paid'] == 1) { // show it } else { // don't show it }`

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested but I think this will give `$result['paid'] >= 1` if the user has paid or the post is free or `$result['paid'] == 0` if it isn't free and the user hasn't paid:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS paid FROM Post p, Money_paid mp
       WHERE p.amount IS NULL OR (mp.post_id = p.id AND mp.user_id = :user_id)
```

In short, `if($result['paid'] == 0)` don't show or if you like `if($result['paid'] >= 1)` do show.

Based on your comment to get the post data:

```
SELECT p.title, p.content FROM Post p, Money_paid mp
       WHERE p.amount IS NULL OR (mp.post_id = p.id AND mp.user_id = :user_id)
```

Then use the `num_rows()` or equivalent function from your DB API to decide whether to show it.

Comment: This query should not need a sub-select or case.

Comment: The idea of your query is great .. But actually your query is *incomplete*. Your query just checks whether should I show such a post to current user or not, While my query *(in the question)* both checks and fetch the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this query is the best, but it works:

```
select *, 
     case when p.amount is null then '1'
          else (select count(1) 
                  from Money_paid mp 
                where mp.post_id = p.id and mp.user_id = :user_id limit 1)
     end paid
from Posts p 
where p.id = :post_id
```

So `$result['paid']` will be `1` for both users who paid the cost and free posts. And it will be `0` for unpaid users.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(*) from ( select * from Posts p innerjoin Money_Paid mp on p.id=mp.post_id ) where id=:post_id and ( amount is null or user_id=:user_id)
```